# How do I change Listener port in Powershell/winrm 2.0?

Tags: windows, powershell, winrm

In [quite](http://www.symantec.com/business/support/index?page=content&id=TECH97514) [a few](http://dbastas.blogspot.co.nz/2009/06/how-to-configure-winrm-in-windows.html) [places](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/zh/winserverpowershell/thread/4fc8b40d-ec1a-4c34-8198-308c23f4a220) the command for changing the port winrm listens on look like this:

```
winrm set winrm/config/Listener?Address=*+Transport=HTTP @{Port="8888"}
```

However this does not work for me. The error I'm getting is:

```
Error: Invalid use of command line. Type "winrm -?" for help.
```

Obviously, internet can't be wrong, so that's me doing something incorrectly. The question is, how to do this correctly?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. Open a PowerShell window with administrative privileges.
2. Run `dir WSMan:\localhost\listener\*\Port` and check the **Value** parameter to see what you're currently listening on.
3. If you'd like to change it, run `Set-Item WSMan:\localhost\listener\*\Port 8888`

If you'd still like to do it with `winrm`, you need to modify your command to the following --

```
winrm set winrm/config/Listener?Address=*+Transport=HTTP '@{Port="8888"}'
```

Comment: You might need to restart the WinRM service afterwards for the change  to take effect. +1

Comment: does "Set-Item" has any advantage over "winrm set"?

Comment: I believe this Microsoft blog post would supplement this answer nicely by adding more alternatives and client-side configuration https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/christwe/2012/06/20/what-port-does-powershell-remoting-use/